# How to know one system is siginficantly better than another one?

Tags: statistics

I am studying lexical semantics. I have 65 pairs of synonyms with their sense relatedness. The dataset is derived from the paper:

Rubenstein, Herbert, and John B. Goodenough. "Contextual correlates of synonymy." Communications of the ACM 8.10 (1965): 627-633.

I extract sentences containing those synonyms, transfer the neighbouring words appearing in those sentences to vectors, calculate the cosine distance between different vectors, and finally get the Pearson correlation between the distances we calculate and the sense relatedness given by Rubenstein and Goodenough

I get the Pearson correlation for Method 1 is 0.79, and for Method 2 is 0.78, for example. How do I measure Method 1 is significantly better than Method 2 or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well Strictly not a programming question, but since this question is unanswered in others stackexchange sites, i'll tell the approach i would take.

I would say there are other benchmarks to check your approaches on similar tasks. You can check how your method performs on those benchmarks and analyze the results. Some methods may capture similarity more while others relatedness and some both.

This is the link [WordVec Demo](http://www.wordvectors.org/index.php) which automatically scores your vectors and provides you the results.